# How to implement a "look back" feature with Flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have digital journaling app that runs on Firebase services and Flutter (more details on our current stack below). We are currently exploring approaches to implement a feature that sends push notifications (via **FCM**) to users with a **`look back`** type summary of their past entries for that day (similar to the **“on this day”** feature of Google Photos).  It would say something along the lines of **“You wrote 3 entries on this date.”**  Once per day, each user will need to be checked to determine if they have entries from the past that fall within the current logic of “look back” eligible entries (which may be subject to change over time). If they have such entries, a push notification is then queued and sent to the user at a time suited to them (we have current architecture which handles this processing of scheduled push notification tasks at their preferred time).

Since this is a potentially expensive operation when scaled to hundreds of thousands of users, we are taking the time to determine the exact best approach taking into consideration these considerations:

### **Considerations:**

The approach should scale, in order to avoid exceeding Firebase cloud function timeouts and memory limits even with hundreds of thousands of users (For example, processing a list of `N` users or `N` entries each in a single cloud function instance should be avoided).
Limit unnecessary Firestore reads and Cloud function executions in order to minimize the cost at scale.
The approach ideally works for previously created entries.
It ideally should fit within our existing architecture, no additional 3p services, additional data stores or other.
Taking these into account and some initial research, one server/backend-only approach we have considered is to use Firestore triggers for new documents based on the entries collection.  Whenever a user creates a new entry, a lookback push notification is scheduled for that entry.

#### **Considered Approach:**

- **Firebase Document Trigger**

  - Firebase new document trigger schedules a push notification for the end of the upcoming lookback period (in 1 week from today); this is based on when the entry was created.

    - If a notification is already scheduled for this lookback period (the user has already created an entry today), the scheduled one is simply updated (title and body reflect the total number of lookback entries in this period)
  - A recurring cloud function (every minute) checks for scheduled lookback notifications past their scheduled for time and spawns an individual cloud function instance for each that…

    - Sends the notification via FCM Service after checking certain meta-conditions are met.
    - Schedules a new push notification for the end of the next upcoming lookback period (in 3 weeks for 1 month lb period; in 11 months for 1 year lb period, etc)

#### **Potential Cons:**

- While clean and scales as per requirements, it means that entries created before this process began won’t have scheduled lookback notifications, so a process of post-scheduling for existing entries would be required.

### Our Stack:

- Database: Firestore document store

  - Collections:

    - Users - collection for users
    - Entries - collection for entries
    - Tasks - collection for all scheduled push notifications
- Server: Firebase cloud functions with FCM
- Client: Flutter (ios/android/web/macos)

We are looking for any suggestions on how best to approach this given our stack and requirements, with an emphasis on optimized, at-scale solutions.

Do you have any suggestions or know someone who has implemented a similar feature that could provide some guidance?

We have tried approaching this using a background process that runs the lookback entry retrieval logic and schedules the notification via the [Local Notifications package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) on the Flutter client itself, but we found that this sort of client-side approach was not reliable. There were several cases where the process would fail to run, particularly where the user has not opened the app recently. That said, we are open to client-side implementation suggestions as well if they can be guaranteed to work without requiring user interaction.

Comment: In a non-document database, I'd make a many-to-many table of dates and postings (including users).  That would be quick to look up postings for a given user.  Not sure the easiest way in document database, except a lot of denormalized data.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Are you suggesting a separate collection that stores a document for each date that contains a list of all entries for that date? If so, that would be a lot of documents to store and maintain, but it would be a quick lookup. 

But for entries that were created before this feature was implemented, it would be a lot of work to go back and make these documents for each date. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Sure, depends on how accurate you want it to be,.  You could decide on say, a five year cutoff.  And to minimize storage, that could be a rolling window where you actually discard very old data.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz That's a good idea, I will wait to see if anyone else has any suggestions, but I think that's a good approach and will look into it. Thanks again!